How to "apply" Rotation to a armature bone?
I have the following "controller" bone added to my rig:

The problem is, that if I add a "copy rotation" constraint to the bones I want to control, they apply the rotation which I have made to position the controller as well:

I have already tried different options of the constraint (Mix Replace, Add, Before origin, After origin) but none gives the result I expect. Basically I want "apply rotation" to the controller bone and then constraint only relative movement from there. How would this be possible?

Maybe what you want is to set the Target and Owner to Local/Local, this way the bone will keep its default rotation until you rotate its target:

